# In the 90's I read a series of books

Tags: story-identification, magic, history

I can't remember the name, but it had a college age magician who was supposed to have been corrupted by a succubus, but she ended up falling in love with him. In addition to this, there were various historical figures coming back from the dead, including Saladin, King Richard the Lionheart, and several others. I know there were multiple books in the series, but I can't remember any of the titles.